# AS3 SharedObject - Background images fails to load correctly. Set of images stored inside MC fails to load correct image from save

Tags: image, actionscript-3, local-shared-object

having issues with making a set of background images save and load correctly. Please note, that this has worked correctly in the past with "1 - 2" images in the caseSwapper.

**Structure :** 
On my stage I have set of *draggable* objects that you can save and load as you please. (these work)
The background, which is movieClip called "caseSwapper" contains a set of frames with different images inside each frame. E.G frame one is called (labelled) "frameone" - contains a pretty picture. Frame 2 is labelled  "Frametwo" which contains an alternative image etc etc

A load and save button on the stage allows you to store the data to sharedObject "mySO"

**Issues and Behaviour**
On the face of it, the save appears to be working. The trace statement is declaring that the current frame is being stored to mySO... although I'm not entirely convinced it is. Basically, when the player has a certain background selected and they click 'save' I need the current image to be saved/written to the sharedObject.

Notes : Frame 1 appears to work when I click 'load' from the stage. When I 'launch' the application (not load) even after saving frame 123 or 4 only frame 4 launches/dis[lays. I then have to click load to retrieve my sharedObject... which only shows the first frame... Any pointers. Script to edit is at the bottom. Please Note, that I'm designer first and foremost!

```
save_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, clickersave);

function clickersave (e:MouseEvent):void {
    saved.play();
mySO.data.myblcskull_mc_x = blcskull_mc.x;
mySO.data.myblcskull_mc_y = blcskull_mc.y;
mySO.data.myblackhandbag_mc_y = blackhandbag_mc.y;
mySO.data.myblackhandbag_mc_x = blackhandbag_mc.x;      
mySO.data.myhotlips_mc_x = hotlips_mc.x;
mySO.data.myhotlips_mc_y = hotlips_mc.y;    
mySO.data.my_x = bones_mc.x;
mySO.data.my_y = bones_mc.y;
mySO.data.mybut_x = btrfly_mc.x;
mySO.data.mybut_y = btrfly_mc.y;
mySO.data.mytig_x = tiger_mc.x;
mySO.data.mytig_y = tiger_mc.y; 
mySO.data.myskullface_mc_y = skullface_mc.y;
mySO.data.myskullface_mc_x = skullface_mc.x;
mySO.data.myblack_tile_mc_zero_y = black_tile_mc_zero.y;
mySO.data.myblack_tile_mc_zero_x = black_tile_mc_zero.x;
mySO.data.myblack_tile_mc_one_x = black_tile_mc_one.x;
mySO.data.myblack_tile_mc_one_y = black_tile_mc_one.y;  
mySO.data.mycrown_mc_y = crown_mc.y;
mySO.data.mycrown_mc_x = crown_mc.x;
mySO.data.myperfume_mc_y = perfume_mc.y;
mySO.data.myperfume_mc_x = perfume_mc.x;
mySO.data.myheart_mc_x = heart_mc.x;
mySO.data.myheart_mc_y = heart_mc.y;
mySO.data.myrose_mc_y = rose_mc.y;
mySO.data.myrose_mc_x = rose_mc.x;
 // tears saved - - - - -  - -
mySO.data.mytear_drop_mc_one_x = tear_drop_mc_one.x;
mySO.data.mytear_drop_mc_one_y = tear_drop_mc_one.y;
mySO.data.mytearup_drop_mc_three_x = tearup_drop_mc_three.x;
mySO.data.mytearup_drop_mc_three_y = tearup_drop_mc_three.y;
mySO.data.mytearup_drop_mc_four_x = tearup_drop_mc_four.x;
mySO.data.mytearup_drop_mc_four_y = tearup_drop_mc_four.y;
mySO.data.mytear_drop_mc_two_x = tear_drop_mc.x;
mySO.data.mytear_drop_mc_two_y = tear_drop_mc.y;
mySO.data.mytear_side_mc_one_x = tear_side_mc_one.x;
mySO.data.mytear_side_mc_one_y = tear_side_mc_one.y;
mySO.data.mytear_side_mc_two_x = tear_side_mc_two.x;
mySO.data.mytear_side_mc_two_y = tear_side_mc_two.y;
mySO.data.mytear_op_mc_one_y = tear_op_mc_one.y;
mySO.data.mytear_op_mc_one_x = tear_op_mc_one.x;
mySO.data.mytear_op_mc_two_y = tear_op_mc_two.y;
mySO.data.mytear_op_mc_two_x = tear_op_mc_two.x;
//tear_op_mc_one
// pink gems 
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_one_x = pink_jewel_mc_one.x;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_one_y = pink_jewel_mc_one.y;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_two_x = pink_jewel_mc_two.x;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_two_y = pink_jewel_mc_two.y;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_three_x = pink_jewel_mc_three.x;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_three_y = pink_jewel_mc_three.y;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_four_x = pink_jewel_mc_four.x;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_four_y = pink_jewel_mc_four.y;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_five_x = pink_jewel_mc_five.x;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_five_y = pink_jewel_mc_five.y;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_six_x = pink_jewel_mc_six.x;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_six_y = pink_jewel_mc_six.y;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_seven_x = pink_jewel_mc_seven.x;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_seven_y = pink_jewel_mc_seven.y;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_eight_x = pink_jewel_mc_eight.x;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_eight_y = pink_jewel_mc_eight.y;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_nine_x = pink_jewel_mc_nine.x;
mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_nine_y = pink_jewel_mc_nine.y;
// bg saves

mySO.data.myBgFrame = 1;
mySO.data.myBgFrameone = 2;
mySO.data.myBgFrametwo = 3;
mySO.data.myBgFramethree = 4;
trace("bgbackgrounds");

// silver gems - - - - - - - - - 
mySO.data.mycircle_gem_mc_x = circle_gem_mc.x;
mySO.data.mycircle_gem_mc_y = circle_gem_mc.y;
mySO.data.mycircle_gem_mc_two_x = circle_gem_mc_two.x;
mySO.data.mycircle_gem_mc_two_y = circle_gem_mc_two.y;
mySO.data.mycircle_gem_mc_thirteen_x = circle_gem_mc_thirteen.x;
mySO.data.mycircle_gem_mc_thirteen_y = circle_gem_mc_thirteen.y;
//circle_gem_mc_six
mySO.flush ();

}

if (mySO.data.myBgFrame){
    caseSwapper.gotoAndStop(mySO.data.myBgFrame);
}
if (mySO.data.myBgFrameone){
    caseSwapper.gotoAndStop(mySO.data.myBgFrameone);
}
if (mySO.data.myBgFrametwo){
    caseSwapper.gotoAndStop(mySO.data.myBgFrametwo);
}
if (mySO.data.myBgFramethree){
    caseSwapper.gotoAndStop(mySO.data.myBgFramethree);
}

//caseSwapper.currentFrame = mySO.data.myBgFrame;

/////// ---------------------- loader    

// ---------------------- LOADER -------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------
// when load button is clicked it loads the x and y position of dragged objects pulled from the
//sharedOject, it remembers the last var! 
load_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, loadlast);

function loadlast (e:MouseEvent):void {
  //saved.play();       
caseSwapper.gotoAndStop(mySO.data.myBgFrame);
//caseSwapper.currentFrame = mySO.data.myBgFrame;
//caseSwapper.gotoAndStop(mySO.data.myBgFrameone);
//caseSwapper.gotoAndStop(mySO.data.myBgFrametwo);
//caseSwapper.gotoAndStop(mySO.data.myBgFramethree);
//caseSwapper.gotoAndStop(mySO.data.myBgFramefour); 
blcskull_mc.x = mySO.data.myblcskull_mc_x;
blcskull_mc.y = mySO.data.myblcskull_mc_y; 
blackhandbag_mc.y = mySO.data.myblackhandbag_mc_y; 
blackhandbag_mc.x = mySO.data.myblackhandbag_mc_x;      
bones_mc.x = mySO.data.my_x;
bones_mc.y = mySO.data.my_y;
tiger_mc.x = mySO.data.mytig_x;
tiger_mc.y = mySO.data.mytig_y; 
btrfly_mc.x = mySO.data.mybut_x;
btrfly_mc.y = mySO.data.mybut_y;
crown_mc.x = mySO.data.mycrown_mc_x;
crown_mc.y = mySO.data.mycrown_mc_y;
perfume_mc.x = mySO.data.myperfume_mc_x;
perfume_mc.y = mySO.data.myperfume_mc_y;
heart_mc.x = mySO.data.myheart_mc_x;
heart_mc.y = mySO.data.myheart_mc_y;
rose_mc.y = mySO.data.myrose_mc_y;
rose_mc.x = mySO.data.myrose_mc_x;
pink_jewel_mc_one.x = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_one_x; 
pink_jewel_mc_one.y = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_one_y;  
pink_jewel_mc_two.x = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_two_x; 
pink_jewel_mc_two.y = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_two_y;
pink_jewel_mc_three.x = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_three_x; 
pink_jewel_mc_three.y = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_three_y;
pink_jewel_mc_four.x = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_four_x; 
pink_jewel_mc_four.y = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_four_y;
pink_jewel_mc_five.x = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_five_x; 
pink_jewel_mc_five.y = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_five_y;
pink_jewel_mc_six.x = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_six_x; 
pink_jewel_mc_six.y = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_six_y;
pink_jewel_mc_seven.x = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_seven_x; 
pink_jewel_mc_seven.y = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_seven_y;
pink_jewel_mc_eight.x = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_eight_x; 
pink_jewel_mc_eight.y = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_eight_y;
pink_jewel_mc_nine.x = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_nine_x; 
pink_jewel_mc_nine.y = mySO.data.mypink_jewel_mc_nine_y;
hotlips_mc.x = mySO.data.myhotlips_mc_x;
hotlips_mc.y = mySO.data.myhotlips_mc_y;
tearup_drop_mc_three.y = mySO.data.mytearup_drop_mc_three_y;
tearup_drop_mc_three.x = mySO.data.mytearup_drop_mc_three_x;
tearup_drop_mc_four.x = mySO.data.mytearup_drop_mc_four_x;
tearup_drop_mc_four.y = mySO.data.mytearup_drop_mc_four_y;
tear_side_mc_one.x = mySO.data.mytear_side_mc_one_x;
tear_side_mc_one.y = mySO.data.mytear_side_mc_one_y;
//tear_side_mc_two.x = mySO.data.mytear_side_mc_two_x; 
//tear_side_mc_two.y = mySO.data.mytear_side_mc_two_y;
tear_op_mc_one.y = mySO.data.mytear_op_mc_one_y;
tear_op_mc_one.x = mySO.data.mytear_op_mc_one_x;
tear_op_mc_two.y = mySO.data.mytear_op_mc_two_y;
tear_op_mc_two.x = mySO.data.mytear_op_mc_two_x;
//--- silver little gems -----------------
circle_gem_mc_thirteen.x = mySO.data.mycircle_gem_mc_thirteen_x;
circle_gem_mc_thirteen.y = mySO.data.mycircle_gem_mc_thirteen_y;
circle_gem_mc_two.x = mySO.data.mycircle_circle_gem_mc_two_x;
circle_gem_mc_two.y = mySO.data.mycircle_circle_gem_mc_two_y;
mySO.flush ();      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually storing the current frame anywhere — this section just saves the same numbers every time:

```
mySO.data.myBgFrame = 1;
mySO.data.myBgFrameone = 2;
mySO.data.myBgFrametwo = 3;
mySO.data.myBgFramethree = 4;
```

This is also why you're only seeing frame four when you launch, because all of your `if` statements see a positive number (and anything other than zero or `NaN` counts as `true`), so they all get executed one after the other.

Instead of the above, all you need is this in your save function:

```
mySO.data.myBgFrame = caseSwapper.currentFrame;
```

Then if you want to jump to that frame on launch, you only need your first `if` statement:

```
if (mySO.data.myBgFrame){
    caseSwapper.gotoAndStop(mySO.data.myBgFrame);
}
```

Comment: Thank you David, I will test this in the morning!

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for you help. What does "NaN" mean out of interest?

Comment: Great! NaN stands for "Not a Number", and it's what you get if you try to do something like `var result:Number = 0 / 0`.